Codefresh Tagging Pipeline
I have a codefresh Pipeline, where I seem to be getting cyclical errors in the YAML Formatting Linter used by Codefresh. Though, before I open a support ticket, I wanted the community to check my logic, as maybe I am missing something here.
Here is my pipeline:
version: "1.0"
stages:
  - "clone"
  - "bump_version"
  - "push_tag"

steps:
  clone_repo:
    title: "Cloning repository"
    type: "git-clone"
    repo: "${{CF_REPO_NAME}}"
    revision: "${{CF_BRANCH}}"
    stage: "clone"

  detect_last_tag:
    title: "Detecting last tag"
    type: "freestyle"
    image: "alpine/git"
    stage: "bump_version"
    commands:
      - |
        LAST_TAG=$(git describe --tags --abbrev=0 || echo '0.0.0')
        echo "LAST_TAG=\"$LAST_TAG\"" > /codefresh/volume/env_vars_to_export/env_vars
    volumes:
      - name: env_vars_to_export
        path: /codefresh/volume/env_vars_to_export

  determine_new_version:
    title: "Determining new version"
    type: "freestyle"
    image: "alpine/git"
    stage: "bump_version"
    commands:
      - |
        source /codefresh/volume/env_vars_to_export/env_vars
        echo "Last tag is $LAST_TAG"

        # Extract version components
        MAJOR=$(echo "$LAST_TAG" | cut -d. -f1)
        MINOR=$(echo "$LAST_TAG" | cut -d. -f2)
        PATCH=$(echo "$LAST_TAG" | cut -d. -f3)

        # Convert to strings explicitly
        MAJOR="${MAJOR}"
        MINOR="${MINOR}"
        PATCH="${PATCH}"
        echo "MAJOR: \"$MAJOR\", MINOR: \"$MINOR\", PATCH: \"$PATCH\""

        # Determine the new version based on PR description
        if echo "$CF_PULL_REQUEST_DESCRIPTION" | grep -q "#major"; then
          MAJOR=$((MAJOR + 1))
          MAJOR="${MAJOR}"
          MINOR="0"
          PATCH="0"
        elif echo "$CF_PULL_REQUEST_DESCRIPTION" | grep -q "#minor"; then
          MINOR=$((MINOR + 1))
          MINOR="${MINOR}"
          PATCH="0"
        else
          PATCH=$((PATCH + 1))
          PATCH="${PATCH}"
        fi

        NEW_TAG="${MAJOR}.${MINOR}.${PATCH}"
        echo "NEW_TAG=\"$NEW_TAG\"" > /codefresh/volume/env_vars_to_export/env_vars
    volumes:
      - name: env_vars_to_export
        path: /codefresh/volume/env_vars_to_export

  push_tag:
    title: "Pushing new tag"
    type: "freestyle"
    image: "alpine/git"
    stage: "push_tag"
    commands:
      - |
        source /codefresh/volume/env_vars_to_export/env_vars
        echo "Tagging with NEW_TAG: \"$NEW_TAG\""
        git tag "$NEW_TAG"
        git push origin "$NEW_TAG"
    volumes:
      - name: env_vars_to_export
        path: /codefresh/volume/env_vars_to_export


The errors I am getting are:
LINE 15
"0" must be a string. Current value: [object Object]
LEARN MORE
Please make sure you have all the required fields and valid values

LINE 28
"0" must be a string. Current value: [object Object]
LEARN MORE
Please make sure you have all the required fields and valid values

LINE 70
"0" must be a string. Current value: [object Object]
LEARN MORE
Please make sure you have all the required fields and valid values

The pipeline is supposed to tag things, if no tag is found, tag with 0.0.0. But it seems that Codefresh does not like my pipelines. Am I not interpolating my zeros correctly?

I opened a support ticket on this:
https://support.codefresh.io/hc/en-us/requests/22544

I think though, that the issue might actually be a bug with Codefresh in terms of how it validates strings v. integers...

Apparently the Codefresh Validator fails on specifying volumes:
version: '1.0'
stages:
  - "clone"
  - "bump_version"
  - "push_tag"

steps:
  clone_repo:
    title: "Cloning repository"
    type: "git-clone"
    repo: "${{CF_REPO_NAME}}"
    revision: "${{CF_BRANCH}}"
    stage: "clone"

  detect_last_tag:
    title: "Detecting last tag"
    type: "freestyle"
    image: "alpine/git"
    stage: "bump_version"
    commands:
      - |
        # Fetch the latest tag or default to "0.0.0"
        LAST_TAG=$(git describe --tags --abbrev=0 || echo "0.0.0")
        echo "Last tag detected: $LAST_TAG"
        # Write the LAST_TAG to a specific file within the volume
        echo "LAST_TAG=$LAST_TAG" > /codefresh/volume/env_vars_to_export/env_vars

  determine_new_version:
    title: "Determining new version"
    type: "freestyle"
    image: "alpine/git"
    stage: "bump_version"
    commands:
      - |
        # Source the environment variables from the specific file
        source /codefresh/volume/env_vars_to_export/env_vars
        echo "Last tag is $LAST_TAG"

        # Extract version components
        IFS='.' read -r -a VERSION <<< "$LAST_TAG"
        MAJOR="${VERSION[0]}"
        MINOR="${VERSION[1]}"
        PATCH="${VERSION[2]}"

        echo "Detected PR message: $CF_PULL_REQUEST_DESCRIPTION"

        # Determine the new version based on PR description
        if echo "$CF_PULL_REQUEST_DESCRIPTION" | grep -q "#major"; then
          MAJOR=$((MAJOR + 1))
          MINOR=0
          PATCH=0
        elif echo "$CF_PULL_REQUEST_DESCRIPTION" | grep -q "#minor"; then
          MINOR=$((MINOR + 1))
          PATCH=0
        else
          PATCH=$((PATCH + 1))
        fi

        NEW_TAG="${MAJOR}.${MINOR}.${PATCH}"
        echo "New tag: $NEW_TAG"
        # Write the NEW_TAG to the same environment variables file
        echo "NEW_TAG=$NEW_TAG" > /codefresh/volume/env_vars_to_export/env_vars

  tag_and_push:
    title: "Tagging and pushing to repository"
    type: "freestyle"
    image: "alpine/git"
    stage: "push_tag"
    commands:
      - |
        # Source the environment variables
        source /codefresh/volume/env_vars_to_export/env_vars
        echo "Tagging with NEW_TAG: \"$NEW_TAG\""
        # Create and push the new tag
        git tag "$NEW_TAG"
        git push origin "$NEW_TAG"

Passed the validation, whether the pipeline works is a different matter though.
But I was told my Codefresh support to remove the following:
volumes:
    - name: env_vars_to_export
      path: /codefresh/volume/env_vars_to_export

Which seemed to work and pass thier validation in the UI.
